# How to define float decimal precision in Android Room table column

Tags: android-room

I know in sqlite we can define column decimal precision with DECIMAL(10,2)
How can this be achieved with Android Room

Eg. I want room table column to store 1000.33, when I insert 1000.3333333333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define the precision.

All **REAL** *(the storage class used for decimal/float/double values)* values are stored in SQLite as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number. An alternative approach would be store the value as a String **BUT** not a String that can be considered a numeric e.g. (as it would be stored as such) you could store the value `D1000.33`. i.e. the D ensures that the value is stored/retrieved as a String.

- see [DataTypes in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

You need to apply the required precision when (e.g. using the [SQLite round function](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round)) or after you extract the value.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your answer. So the conclusion is: While making query we have to handle the decimal precision as per the requirement.

Comment: @RahulSinghal or after making the query when the object (entity) has been retrieved.